# Pip can't find module pip._internal.utils

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation

I did a fresh install of Python 3.8.3 for Windows 10. I can't get pip to work, it keeps complaining about module pip._internal.utils that can't be found.

When I run `pip -v` as a regular user, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\verhager\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.typing import MYPY_CHECK_RUNNING
  File "C:\Users\verhager\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pip._internal.utils.inject_securetransport  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.utils'
```

I have tried reinstalling, rebooting, running as Administrator, reinstalling pip with get_pip.py, but nothing has worked sofar.

When searching, I found several people having similar issues on different OSes. It seems like I've tried all suggested solutions, but nothing has worked for me sofar.

Comment: What does `py -3 -m pip --version` show?

Comment: Same error, I couldn't start pip. Not through `pip` or `python -m pip`. I managed to solve it later yesterday and will post the solution as answer as it may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling didn't solve my problem. That is, not before I really made sure that nothing was left behind.

My Python install was in `C:\Python38\`. After uninstalling python, this directory remained and contained some left over modules, like pip. I manually deleted the whole `C:\Python38` folder.

Then, I checked my `AppData` folder in my home dir. Everything in this folder and all subfolders that was related to Python or Python modules, I deleted as well. Keep in mind `AppData` is a hidden folder, so it you might have to enable showing of hidden files and folders in the explorer first.

Finally, I removed all Python folders from my PATH environment variables (system as well as user).

After that, I did a new install of Python 3.8 and everything works as expected.

What I think the problem was? Some left overs from a previously (broken) installation messed with my environment, causing `pip` not resolving required modules.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error as you, with Windows 10. I also investigated and found that the "pip._internal.utils" package was missing. I was able to overcome this issue without an extensive Cleanup/Reinstall of Python.

After ensuring the following

- **That the Python Binary and Scripts folders were part of `%PATH%`**
- **That I was on a Console Window with Administrator privileges**

I ran the following command

- **`python -m ensurepip --default-pip`**

With this command the package was installed. I did a general verification  of the installation with the following command.

- **`pip --version`**

Which returned the with specs. This command invokes the missing package.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and here's how I resolved this error on windows 7 -

1. Navigate to C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages
2. Delete pip folder

This is introduced when I read this messsage
"You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comand." and followed using the same command for upgrading.

Comment: python doesn't put itself on Roaming anymore. It's in %appdata%/Local/Programs now.